# set a dynamically created bash variable

Tags: bash, variables, unix

Good morning,
i need to dynamically change the name of a variable. I did some tests. my test script is this:

```
i=5
range5min=777
varname="range${i}min"
echo ${!varname}
#$`echo $varname`=555
$varname=555
echo $range5min
```

I can access its content with:

```
echo $ {! Varname}
```

But I can't set a dynamically created variable with a value, that is, I can't make the assignment of a value with the equal.
I tried both of these ways:

```
$ `echo $ varname` = 555
```

```
$ varname = 555
```

What I would like to do is create new variables inside a for, depending on how many loops the for expects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `printf`:

```
printf -v "$varname" '%s' "555"
```

Note, though, that this type of programming is not really recommended, since it makes code hard to read and understand.

An array or associative array might be more appropriate.